# Accessing object in minio server with javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, minio

I have a minio S3 server running which I'm trying to use as a storage back end for a small [igv.js](https://github.com/igvteam/igv.js/tree/master) webservice running in a docker image.

I'm looking for a way to create a shareable url of an object in the S3 bucket from javascript/php, so I can then feed this url into IGV.js for visualisation.

The webapp is aware of all credentials for the minio server, but I'm unable to find the method to create such URL's. AWS docs just seem to circle around.

Thanks
M

Comment: I see two downvotes, but no explanation. If you'd be so kind to explain what's wrong, I could amend my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use minio-js to create a presigned URL for an object. More details are here - https://docs.minio.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference#presignedUrl